# GeoLocation Zip Code

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I am using the following code for getting location and city, but can't get it to give me the zip code if the person gives me permission. Please let me know if this is possible to do with this code. All it is doing is populating a text field if given permission to access.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     $("#location").val(position.address.city+", "+position.address.region);
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `position.address.postalCode`

See the following demo i made to see what is supported by your browser/device

https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Sx5cj/

Comment: `(index):78 [Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS` in console.

Comment: @Azimuth just use the https:// version of jsfiddle. Have updated the answer as well.

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome. `position.address` is undefined.

Comment: Yeah, Chrome doesn't show it because Google is charging for the service.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the latest [HTML5 Geolocation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/), i do not see the support for `position.address.city`, `position.address.region` or `position.address.city` yet.  So, i'd have to say that is not currently supported.

---

**Update:**

Address look up seems to be supported in firefox per @Gaby aka G. Petrioli answer

Answer (score 5):

There is no support for address in HTML 5 Geolocation API, but you can achieve this combining it with Google Maps API:
here is an example getting the zipCode but you can use it to get the entire address:

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
        new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode(
            {'latLng': point},
            function (res, status) {
                var zip = res[0].formatted_address.match(/,\s\w{2}\s(\d{5})/);
                $("#location").val(zip);          
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: $("#location").val(zip); should be  $("#location").val(zip[1]); otherwise it would return the entire array's contents.

Comment: Not bad idea, but is google api built into modern browsers?

Comment: @KevinDanikowski NO, you include google maps api as a CDN <script src=.. > in your app